# MongooseJS messes up pre-imported data when document is updated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

A piece of my Mongo document structure is:

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxx..."),
"Country" : "UNITED KINGDOM", 
"Line" : "something",
"Records" : [
     {"rdata" : "foo", "rtype" : "X", "name" : "John"}, 
     {"rdata" :  "bar", "rtype" : "Y", "name" : "Bill"}
],  ...
```

I'm using Mongoose to access the data via the following model:

```
var Record = new Schema({
 rdata: String,
 rtype: String,
 name:  String
}, {_id: false});

var ThingSchema = new Schema({
Country: String,
Line : String,
Records : [Record],
```

Let's say I want to update the "Line" property of one of my documents, from being `"Line" : "something"` to `"Line" : "way more interesting"` by sending a PUT request to the appropriate API URL. I can see that the data being sent is all right. This is what the API does:

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
  Thing.findById(req.params.id, function (err, thing) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!thing) { return res.send(404); }
    var updated = _.merge(thing, req.body);
    updated.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.json(200, updated);
    });
  });
};
```

The API comes back with 200/OK - but I see the following updated data:

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxx..."),
"Country" : "UNITED KINGDOM", 
"Line" : "way more interesting",  <-- updated correctly
"Records" : [
     {"rdata" : "foo", "rtype" : "X", "name" : "John"}, 
     {"rdata" :  "foo", "rtype" : "X", "name" : "John"}
],  ...
```

Notice, how the Records array got messed up by overwriting my second record by duplicating the first one. (If I switch on the automatic addition of '_id' to the subdocument by Mongoose, then even the "_id" fields will be the same on the two records within the array).

It may be relevant, that  originally the Records were not added via Mongoose - but by importing a JSON document.  Any suggestion as to how to start finding out why this is happening would be fantastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `_.merge` to `_.extend`, then call save directly on the `thing` document returned by the **`findById()`** method instead of the merged object `updated`:

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
    if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
    Thing.findById(req.params.id, function (err, thing) {
        if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
        if(!thing) { return res.send(404); }
         _.extend(thing, req.body);
        thing.save(function (err) {
            if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
            return res.json(200, thing);
        });
    });
}
```

Another option is using the set method on the entity i.e. `thing.set(req.body)` before calling the save method on the `thing` object.

This **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19966511/)** by ShitalShah highlights the differences between merge and extend that is causing duplicates in your resulting object with merge but essentially:

> Here's how extend/assign works: For each property in source, copy its
>   value as-is to destination. if property values themselves are objects,
>   there is no recursive traversal of their properties. Entire object
>   would be taken from source and set in to destination.
>
> Here's how merge works: For each property in source, check if that
>   property is object itself. If it is then go down recursively and try
>   to map child object properties from source to destination. So
>   essentially we merge object hierarchy from source to destination.
>   While for extend/assign, it's simple one level copy of properties from
>   source to destination.

**[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uXaqIMa/2/edit?js,console)** to illustrate the differences

Comment: @tom.W No worries :-)