# _.merge clones sub-documents instead of updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, merge, lodash

In my `Angular fullstack` project I try to update a project adding a new sub-document to it. When checking my `req.body` before merging it all looks as it should. However after the merge the updated document has added a new sub-document as it should, the only problem is that this new document is a clone of an already existing one, instead of the one it should have been.

the `_.merge` is from `lodash`

the code:

```
    console.log('');
    console.log('notes before merging : ', entry.notes);

    console.log('');
    console.log('body.notes before merging : ', req.body.notes);

    var updated = _.merge(entry, req.body);

    console.log('');
    console.log('notes after merging : ', updated.notes);
```

And my console result when running the code:

```
notes before merging :  
[
    { 
        content: '<p>testing</p>',
        date: Thu Apr 16 2015 10:14:44 GMT+0200 (Rom, sommertid),
        writer: 55193679026666b00554d00e,
        _id: 552f6f7435828478156f6103,
        notes: [] 
    }
]

body.notes before merging :  
[ 
    { 
        content: '<p>testing</p>',
        date: Thu Apr 16 2015 10:14:44 GMT+0200 (Rom, sommertid),
        writer: 55193679026666b00554d00e,
        _id: 552f6f7435828478156f6103,
        notes: [] 
    },
    { 
        content: '<p>bla bla</p>',
        date: '2015-04-16T08:25:24.431Z',
        writer: 55193679026666b00554d00e
    }
]

notes after merging :  
[
    { 
        content: '<p>testing</p>',
        date: Thu Apr 16 2015 10:14:44 GMT+0200 (Rom, sommertid),
        writer: 55193679026666b00554d00e,
        _id: 552f6f7435828478156f6103,
        notes: [] 
    },
    { 
        content: '<p>testing</p>',
        date: Thu Apr 16 2015 10:14:44 GMT+0200 (Rom, sommertid),
        writer: 55193679026666b00554d00e,
        _id: 552f6f7435828478156f6103,
        notes: [] 
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **`_.extend`** or [**`_.assign`**](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) instead:

```
var updated = _.assign(entry, req.body);
```

This **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19966511/)** by ShitalShah highlights the differences between merge and extend that is causing duplicates in your resulting object with merge but essentially:

> Here's how extend/assign works: For each property in source, copy its
>   value as-is to destination. if property values themselves are objects,
>   there is no recursive traversal of their properties. Entire object
>   would be taken from source and set in to destination.
>
> Here's how merge works: For each property in source, check if that
>   property is object itself. If it is then go down recursively and try
>   to map child object properties from source to destination. So
>   essentially we merge object hierarchy from source to destination.
>   While for extend/assign, it's simple one level copy of properties from
>   source to destination.

**[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uXaqIMa/2/edit?js,console)** to illustrate the differences:

```
var dest = {
  p: { x: 10, y: 20},
};

var src = {
  p: { x: 20, z: 30},
};

console.log(_.merge(dest, src)); 
/*
[object Object] {
  p: [object Object] {
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    z: 30
  }
}
*/

console.log(_.extend(dest, src));
/*
[object Object] {
  p: [object Object] {
    x: 20,
    z: 30
  }
}
*/
```