# mongoose won't update object field

Tags: mongodb

I am new to moogoose, i am running into the difficult to update object in the db.

here is my shcema.

```
var FormSchema = new Schema({
  formContent : {
    type : Object,
    required : true
  }, 
  formName : String,
  createdDateTime : Date
});
```

Here is the controller to update the field, i have used '[]' and it works to clean up the field, but whenever i PUT a new object and try to replace, and it just stay the same... any idea or suggestion would be much appreciated. stuck in this for hrs...

```
// Updates an existing form in the DB.
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
  Form.findById(req.params.id, function (err, form) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!form) { return res.send(404); }
    var updated = _.merge(form, req.body);
    // updated.formContent = [];
    updated.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.json(200, form);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Use `form.toObject()` to get a plain object suitable for manipulation.

Comment: @user3561036 where to put it ?? Thanks man still hanging here..

Comment: How about `_merge(form.toObject(), req.body)`. I'd mark the duplicate question but don't have the privilege to cast close votes.

Comment: @user3561036 that throw an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **`_.extend`** or [**`_.assign`**](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) instead:

```
var updated = _.assign(form, req.body);
```

This **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19966511/)** by ShitalShah highlights the differences between merge and extend:

> Here's how extend/assign works: For each property in source, copy its
>   value as-is to destination. if property values themselves are objects,
>   there is no recursive traversal of their properties. Entire object
>   would be taken from source and set in to destination.
>
> Here's how merge works: For each property in source, check if that
>   property is object itself. If it is then go down recursively and try
>   to map child object properties from source to destination. So
>   essentially we merge object hierarchy from source to destination.
>   While for extend/assign, it's simple one level copy of properties from
>   source to destination.

**[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/uXaqIMa/2/edit?js,console)** to illustrate the differences.

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
  Form.findById(req.params.id, function (err, form) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!form) { return res.send(404); }
    var updated = _.assign(form, req.body);
    // updated.formContent = [];
    updated.save(function (err) {
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.json(200, form);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: @bluebill1049 No worries mate ;-)

Comment: Sorry be a pain, Any reason why merge will end up stop updating the field? I really want get this uderstood

Comment: @bluebill1049 In addition to the provided explanation in the answer, this [**gist**](https://gist.github.com/creynders/8934667) explains the differences but basically [**`_.merge()`**](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) will recursively merge the object hierarchy from source to destination and thus it just stays the same.

Comment: @bluebill1049 No problem, glad to be of help.