# Add new properties of object in lodash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I've two objects and I want to add properties from object A to object B and I try with **extend** which doesn't work,do I need to use something different ?

```
a = {
name = "value"
name2 = "value2"
}

b = {
name3 = "value"
name4 = "value2"
}
```

I want that A will contain both

```
a = {
name = "value"
name2 = "value2"
name3 = "value"
name4 = "value2"
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`_.extend` (now called [`_.assign`](https://lodash.com/docs#assign)) is indeed how you do this:

```
_.assign(a, b);
```

Live Example:

```js
const a = {
    name: "value",
    name2: "value2",
};

const b = {
    name3: "value",
    name4: "value2",
};

_.assign(a, b);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Though as of ES2015, you don't need Lodash for it, you can use the native [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

Live Example:

```js
const a = {
    name: "value",
    name2: "value2",
};

const b = {
    name3: "value",
    name4: "value2",
};

Object.assign(a, b);
console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks I try it but after the assign was called I see the properties in object A but with undefiend values,why?

Answer (score 7):

First of all, your defined objects are incorrect. Objects must be written as `name:value` pairs, separated by a **colon** (and not by an equality sign). Furthermore, you must use **comma separators** to delimit the properties of the object, like:

```
var person = {
    firstName: "Matthias",
    lastName: "Eckhart",
    eyeColor: "blue"
};
```

---

To extend an object with various properties via [lodash](https://lodash.com), you can use [`_.assign(object, [sources], [customizer], [thisArg])`](https://lodash.com/docs#assign):

```js
var a = {
  name: "value",
  name2: "value2"
};

var b = {
  name3: "value",
  name4: "value2"
};

_.assign(a, b); // extend

console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want to use the lodash `merge` function, rather than `extend`. See: [Lodash - difference between .extend() / .assign() and .merge()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965844/lodash-difference-between-extend-assign-and-merge)

Comment: thanks but when I use merge the values of the new properties in 'undefined' why?

Comment: See @t-j-crowder's answer, seems to be working fine.