# Merge objects based on key in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have 4 separate array of objects, is there a way to join all of them into one big object based on the keys inside an object.

Here is an example
**OUTPUT:** what I want to achieve.

```
[
{
    "bugId": "",
    "testerId": "",
    "firstName": "",
    "lastName": "",
    "country": "",
    "deviceId":"",
    "description":""
}
]
```

---

Object of `testers`(It's more than 500)

```
[  
   {  
      "testerId":"1",
      "firstName":"John",
      "lastName":"Doe",
      "country":"US",
   }
]
```

Object for `bugId` (This should be the main object from where we will be able to get the output)
As `deviceId` is connected to `description` and `testerId` is connected to `firstName`, `lastName` and `Country`.

```
[  
   {  
      "bugId":"1",
      "deviceId":"1",
      "testerId":"1"
   }
]
```

Object for `tester_devices`, one tester is provided 4 devices

```
[  
   {  
      "testerId":"1",
      "deviceId":"1"
   },
   {  
      "testerId":"1",
      "deviceId":"2"
   },
   {  
      "testerId":"1",
      "deviceId":"3"
   },
   {  
      "testerId":"1",
      "deviceId":"10"
   }
]
```

Object of `devices`

```
[  
   {  
      "deviceId":"1",
      "description":"iPhone 4"
   }
]
```

I searched for [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) Library, but **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965844/lodash-difference-between-extend-assign-and-merge)** it's mentioned that for key with same name it's not possible to merge. What approach should I take?

Comment: You could just use Lodash's [`_.keyBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#keyBy) to convert your `testers` and `devices` arrays into objects, keyed by their respective IDs. Then you can just iterate your `bugs` array and build up the related data

Comment: How should `tester_devices` play into this? Is it relevant at all?

Comment: `tester_devices`, it can be avoided. As have to search based on the device name, which I can substitute with the number i.e `deviceId`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collect the testers, and the devices into separate [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b). 
Iterate the bugs array with [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and combine objects from both Maps by their ids using [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
const testers = [{"testerId":"1","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","country":"US"}];
const bugs = [{"bugId":"1","deviceId":"1","testerId":"1"}];
const devices = [{"deviceId":"1","description":"iPhone 4"}];

const createMap = (arr, key) => arr.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o[key], o), new Map());

const testersMap = createMap(testers, 'testerId');
const devicesMap = createMap(devices, 'deviceId');

const merged = bugs.map(({ bugId, testerId, deviceId }) => Object.assign({ bugId }, testersMap.get(testerId), devicesMap.get(deviceId)));

console.log(merged);
```