# Changing React State Array at Specific Index

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, setstate

As the title suggests, I'm attempting to target an array inside of my `state object` but as you would guess if you ever tried. This isn't as straightforward as it sounds. I've looked through a couple of questions here ([React: How do I update state.item[1] on setState? (with JSFiddle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537299/react-how-do-i-update-state-item1-on-setstate-with-jsfiddle) and [ReactJS - setState of Object key in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174489/reactjs-setstate-of-object-key-in-array)) but neither are solving my problem.

What I need is to target a specific index inside of the `noteData` array, and update it according to whatever a user types into the `<TextArea />` component. Not exactly sure why but my `noteData` array just read as an array with an empty string `noteData = ['']`.

If you need a more in-depth look, you can go to https://stackblitz.com/edit/note-taking and fork the page and edit it yourself. The file structure is goofy to the say the least. I started using redux and decided against it halfway through.

### state and functions TextArea

```
class NoteList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue: '',
      noteName: [],
      noteData: [],
      selectedNote: []
    }
}

  handleInputValue(e) {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: e.target.value
    });
  }

  addNoteFunc(e) {
    this.setState({
      noteName: [ ...this.state.noteName, e.target.value ],
      noteData: [ ...this.state.noteData, '' ]
    });
  }

 // everytime the user types, change the value of noteData
  handleNoteData(e, index = this.state.selectedNote[0]) {
    const copyNoteData = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    copyNoteData.noteData[index] = e.target.value;

    this.setState(copyNoteData);
  }

  handleSelectedNote(index) {
    this.setState({
      selectedNote: [ index ]
    });
  }

<textarea 
  value={this.state.noteData[this.state.selectedNote[0]]}
  handleNoteData={(e, index) => this.handleNoteData(e, index)}
/>
```

### The actual TextArea component

```
import React from 'react';

const TextArea = props => {
  return (
    <div className='textarea'>
      <textarea 
        value={props.value}
        onKeyDown={props.handleNoteData}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default TextArea;
```

Comment: `index` will always be undefined in this setup. Here you are expecting index: `handleNoteData={(e, index) => this.handleNoteData(e, index)}`, but in you're not passing that in here `onKeyDown={props.handleNoteData}`. So `index` will always end up being the same thing. That may be the reason.

Comment: And your `handleSelectedNote` function is overwriting the state each time with a new array. So `this.state.selectedNote` will never have a length more than 1.

Comment: So `state.selectedNote` is supposed to be a length of 1, always. It is as the name suggests, the currently selected note which can only be one. In my `handleNoteData` func, im not sure if I'm doing it right but the `index` argument is defined as `this.state.selectedNote[0]`... `handleNoteData(e, index = this.state.selectedNote[0])` so I should not need to pass a value later on, as it has already been defined, or am I using this incorrectly?

Comment: Why is it in an array then? Couldn't you just save the `index` as a number?

Comment: I guess it could, but I was not sure if reading a string that is a number could be referenced later as an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have error in your code, as textarea is not the correct component it should be TextArea and not textarea which is a html element, and you will first have to first import it in notelist.js, That is why onKeyDown props is not being set.

```
<TextArea 
   value={this.state.noteData[this.state.selectedNote[0]]}
   handleNoteData={(e, index) => this.handleNoteData(e, index = this.state.selectedNote[0])}
/>
```

Also you must add handleNoteData to onChange event otherwise in onKeyDown event texarea value wil never change since you are resetting it to e.target.value each time.

try this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/note-taking-y5hwsb?file=containers/notelist.js

Comment: Wow, that is a pretty bad typo on my part, thanks for catching that. So how would you suggest instead of it statically rendering 'Hello', I am able to reference an index of `noteData` and use the value of that instead?

Comment: `copyNoteData.noteData[index] = 'Hello'` you are setting it to Hello, what do you want it to be?