# Angular - Compare object model to initial model value in view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, model

I am trying to detect changes to the properties of a model called '`invoice`' so that a button can be enabled only when the values of this object are not the same as those of the initial model, '`initModel`', created when the component was initialised.

So I need to be able to compare the two in the view like this:

```
<button mat-button (click)="saveChanges()" [disabled]="invoice !== initModel">Save Changes</button>
```

The 'invoice' model is initialised by giving it the value of another variable from a service in the constructor.

I've tried to figure out a way of setting an 'initModel' component variable, but this obviously binds with the 'invoice' model, so when the 'invoice' changes, the 'initModel' changes as well, and I can't set 'initModel' as a const that can be accessed in the view.

**Component:**

```
export class EditInvoiceComponent implements OnInit {

  invoice: Invoice;
  initModel;

  constructor(private invoicesService: InvoicesService) {
    this.invoice = this.invoicesService.selectedInvoice;
    this.initModel = this.invoice;
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you initialise `initModel` ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include it

Answer (score 0):

When you initialise `initModel` you are not creating a new object, you are simply passing a reference to the existing `invoice` object.

You can use the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to create a clone ([not a deep clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416020/deep-copy-in-es6-using-the-spread-sign), mind you) of the initial object:

`this.initModel = {...this.invoice};`

If you require deep cloning you can use external libraries (like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep)), have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks. This is kind of working to set the initModel as a copy of the initial model value, but when the component loads, even though both models are the same, a comparison with !== says that they aren't

Comment: I've logged both models to the console, however, and they are exact matches

Comment: Well, that's correct, because they are not the same object. I believe you have two options. The first (hacky) one is to do this: `JSON.stringify(this.initModel) === JSON.stringify(this.invoice)`, while the second (preferred) one is to use an external library (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects))

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

```
$scope.isInvoiceValueChange=false;
$scope.$watch('invoice', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
                // Your logic here to validate value change with  initModel
            $scope.isInvoiceValueChange= true |false ; // based on your logic
},true); // use true if you need to watch nasted prop to trace 


<button mat-button (click)="saveChanges()" [disabled]="isInvoiceValueChange">Save Changes</button>
```

Comment: This is an angular 2+ question, not AngularJS