# Three dots syntax not copying array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to react/javascript paradigm. So i have picked up a course a freecodingcamp.org to start learning. I am currently getting an error at this implementation (https://youtu.be/kqi4gPfdVHY?list=PLmexTtcbIn_hvPcUm3oAufCtH7dwNAC-g&t=2447)

Here is the code for `addLike` button. The error is that when I "update" the song, the new updated songs list doesn't have all values (the size of the array is same but first element is 0). Specifically these two lines in the code

```
      const songData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(updateSong, {input: song}))
      const songList = [...songs];
```

Now, I am no javascript expert so i am not sure why `...` syntax isn't copying the error to new array. it just copies one element and thats it. what am i doing wrong?

**FULL CODE**

```
function App() {

  const [songs, setSongs] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSongs()
  }, [])

  const fetchSongs = async () => {
    try {
      const songData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listSongs));
      const songList = songData.data.listSongs.items;
      console.log('song list', songList);
      setSongs(songList)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error on fetching songs', error)
    }
  }

  const addLike = async(idx) => {
    try {
      const song = songs[idx];
      song.like = song.like + 1;
      delete song.createdAt;
      delete song.updatedAt;
      const songData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(updateSong, {input: song}))
      const songList = [...songs];
      songList[idx] = songData.data.updateSongs;
      setSongs(songList);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error on adding like to the song', error)
    }
  }
```

Comment: [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) creates a shallow copy meaning that nested objects are not copied, but passed as references. As a result, when you change `songList[idx]` you are mutating state. See:[Deep copy in ES6 using the spread syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416020/deep-copy-in-es6-using-the-spread-syntax) and [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react/50149659#50149659)

Comment: Okay but the problem isn't if i am changing state etc. the problem is that the `songList` (the newly created one) has same size as original array but the first element is undefined hence giving me error. If i refresh the page, then it renders fine and thats because of `fetchSongs` effect

Comment: If refreshing the page, and thus resetting the state is 'fixing' it then it absolutely sounds like a state mutation problem. In fact, you are mutating it from the first line in the `try` when you directly access an element from the state array.

Comment: Hmm, I could be totally wrong but if that was the case then this `adsLike` method should throw an exception. Shouldn't it ? It's not throwing any. Exception is being thrown where I am using songs to render html in loop ... And on first iteration I get exception since item 0 is null

Comment: The problem was `songList[idx] = songData.data.updateSongs` ... my operation name is `updateSong` so this line should be `songList[idx] = songData.data.updateSong` (notice no s at the end of the song). Since there was an `s`, the `songList[0]` was being set to undefined :D