# splice method deletes the elements in two arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following error. When I use splice in 1 array, it deletes the element in both arrays.
Code:

```
export class AgendarpacientesComponent implements OnInit {
   arrayPrueba: number[]=[1,2,3,4,5]
}

constructor(){
  this.metodo();
}
ngOnInit() {}

metodo(){
  let arrayAux = this.arrayPrueba;
  arrayAux.splice(1,1);
  console.log(this.arrayPrueba);
}
```

the result of console log is: [1,3,4,5] and I've used the splice method only on arrayAux. I don't know why this is happening.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: `let arrayAux = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.arrayPrueba));`  in order to not have the same reference.

Comment: `this.arrayPrueba.slice()` will also get a new array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two references to the same array. Changes made to any reference, affect the same object. Use something like spread operator to make a copy :

```
let arrayAux = [...this.arrayPrueba];
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked! I didnt know that operation makes a reference to the same object. Thanks !!

Comment: It is a simple '=' (assignment operator). That is what it does for objects/arrays etc. For primitive values like strings, numbers you can use it but not for this.

Comment: I get it. What should I do in cases like classes? for ex. i've tried something like this 'let obj= {...this.otherobj}' and if I exec splice method in some array of 'obj', otherobj is affected too.

Comment: It aint that simple if your objects are nested. Have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416020/deep-copy-in-es6-using-the-spread-syntax