# Update array in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

This is what I have in the state variable

```
this.state = {
            check: 0,
            places: ["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    }
  }
```

What I am trying to do is call a function to update desired value of a location.
For example, I'm using `changeValue` function like this:

```
changeValue= (event) => {

        this.setState({
            places[2]: "1",
        });
  }
```

And it's not working. I know I can pass a fully updated array but I need the other values of the current state.

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537299/react-how-do-i-update-state-item1-on-setstate-with-jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you get the rest of the current places array (and copy it to ensure you don't mutate the state outside setState):

```
changeValue = (event) => {
  const places = this.state.places.slice();
  places[2] = '1';
  this.setState({ places });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your constructor.

```
this.changeValue = this.changeValue.bind(this);
```

In addition to the other answer here, you'll also need to bind the function in the constructor for it to work, especially if you're trying to handle the event via a callback from the child.

Answer (score 0):

setState take object as an argument with key as state key. make sure you pass the right key to update the state.

Try this--->

> ```
> changeValue= (event) => {
>         this.setState({
>             places: places.map((item, index) => { 
>                             if(index == 2) return 1;
>                             return item;  
>                     });
>         });   }
> ```