# How to edit specific fields of object in the array at the same time in setState

Tags: javascript, react-native

How do we create specific fields of object in the array?

Here is my state data that I want to **partially** update.

```
state.items = [
     {id:0, left: 100, right: 100, classified: true},
     {id:1, left: 200, right: 300, classified: false}, 
]
```

And this is expected result after setState.

```
// Edit left, right, classified with given values,
// where the object's id is equal to 1.
state.items = [
     {id:0, left: 100, right: 100, classified: true},
     {id:1, left: 300, right: 200, classified: true}, 
]
```

Here is code inside of function (Problem)

```
//console.log(id) <- prints 1. We are modifying the second object in the array with id 1.

// iterate items array
let { items } = this.state;
for (var index in items) { 
  if(items[index].id === id) {
     // copy the whole object matching id is 1.
     var deep = _.cloneDeep(tag); 

     //Assign new values (newLeft: 300, newRight:200, newCalssified: true)
     deep.left = newLeft
     deep.right = newRight
     deep.classified = newClassified

    this.setState({
      // HERE IS THE QUESTION
      taggedClothes // how do we modify the object with id 1??
    })
  }
}
```

THANKS!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the entire `items` array and then do a `setState` to update that entire `items` array.

```
const items = _.cloneDeep(this.state.items);

// Find index to modify
const index = items.findIndex(i => i.id === id);
items[index].left = newLeft;
items[index].right = newRight;
items[index].classified = newClassified;

this.setState({items});
```

**EDIT:** as mentioned below, it is not always a good idea to mutate the state. I have added a `_.cloneDeep` at the beginning but have a look at this post for more info and other options: [React: How do I update state.item[1] on setState? (with JSFiddle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537299/react-how-do-i-update-state-item1-on-setstate-with-jsfiddle)

Comment: Yes, the solution is to modify the entire items array.

Answer (score 1):

@klugjo's answer is correct but to change reference make a deep clone of current state to change state:

```
const {items} = _.cloneDeep(this.state);

// Find index to modify
const index = items.findIndex(i => i.id === id);
items[index].left = newLeft;
items[index].right = newRight;
items[index].classified = newClassified;

this.setState({ items });
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in previous answers you have to modify the entire `items` array. Here is another approach to do the same using `reduce` in a cleaner way.

```
this.setState({
  items: this.state.items.reduce(function(acc, item) {
    if (item.id === id) {
      item.left = newLeft;
      item.right = newRight;
      item.classified = newClassified;
    }
    acc.push(item);
    return acc;
  }, [])
});
```

Comment: It can't compile it somehow

Comment: expected , on the the line }, []);

Comment: updated the answer, there was extra semicolon added at `}, []);`. Remove it.

Comment: But somehow it deletes the items state. I 'm not sure why it's doing that

Comment: I really prefer your way though because my states are heavy now

Comment: OH items should be items[index]. The problem was the array's element not the array (items)

Comment: I think I have to stick with klugjo's problem...??? Is there any way to improve your answer??

Comment: not sure about the problem you are facing with this solution, but I too suggest you to pick one working solution and check later if there is any updated better answer.