# Set state for array of object

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component that has a state attribute called `Report`. It conforms to the following interface:

```
interface Report {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  otherinfo: info[];
}

interface info {
  dob: string;
  gender: string;
  email: string;
}
```

I'd like to know the preferred way of doing `setState` if I want to update the value of `email`.

Comment: Use filtering, array spread, and object spread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: How do I update state.item\[1\] on setState? (with JSFiddle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537299/react-how-do-i-update-state-item1-on-setstate-with-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method where `report` is the state variable holding your Report object.

```
UpdateEmail(emailValue, index){
  let report = {...this.state.report};
  let info = [...report.otherinfo];
  let newInfoObj = info[index] //index of the state object u want to update
  newInfoObj.email = emailValue;
  info[index] = newInfoObj;
  report.otherinfo = info;
  this.setState({report : report});
}
```

Comment: This is the safest way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this should work.

```
const targetIndex = 0; // assuming this is the index of the element you want to update
const newEmail = 'email@example.com'; // new email address to be set

this.setState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  report: {
    ...prevState.report,
    otherinfo: prevState.report.otherinfo.reduce((accum: info[], currrent: info, currentIndex: number) => {
      if (currentIndex === targetIndex) { // this is where we're trying to find the element with the matching index
        return [
          ...accum,
          {
            ...current,
            email: newEmail, // this is where we set the new email
          }
        ]
      }
      return [...accum, current];
    }, [])
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could use [Immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) for your use case? Something along the lines of:

`const newReport = update(report, { otherinfo: { email: { $set: newEmail }}});
    this.setState({report: newReport})`