# Updating a React state variable throws cross-origin error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pywebview

### Context

At the moment I am working on a project where I want to get data, more specifically a list/Array of Strings, from my Python API and display that list with React.
I am getting the list and it looks completely fine. No `undefined` values, everything is a `String` and it really is an `Array`. So the **retrieved data appears to be valid**.
After retrieving the data I want to set it as a state variable in React so that I can pass it to another component as a prop.

I am using [pywebview](https://pywebview.flowrl.com/) as a React GUI for my Python application. The JavaScript modules are being bundled by webpack.

### Error

Whenever I call `setCourses()` I am getting the following error and React shows a whitescreen.

> Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to
> the actual error object in development. See
> https://reactjs.org/docs/cross-origin-errors.html for more
> information.

### What I have noticed/tried

- when calling `setCourses(["foo0", foo1", "foo2"]);` this error is not thrown.
- when calling `setCourses(new Array(response));` it does not throw an error but somehow joins the Arrays elements to a new Array with the size of 1: ["foo0", "foo1", "foo2"] -> ["foo0,foo1,foo2"].
- iterating over the Array and constructing a new one + checking that every element is a String
- the [error page of React](https://reactjs.org/docs/cross-origin-errors.html) mentioned using the `cheap-module-source-map` setting in case one is using webpack. Setting this didn't help either.

### Similar questions (which didn't solve my poblem)

- [Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611310/uncaught-error-a-cross-origin-error-was-thrown-react-doesnt-have-access-to-th)
- [Correct modification of state arrays in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-react-js)
- [I can't update state for array item in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154713/i-cant-update-state-for-array-item-in-react-native)

### Simplified code snippet

As you can see below, I am fetching the data from the Python API in a `useEffect` hook and trying to set the state which shall rerender my component so that the child component `<CourseList courses={courses} />` will display the courses.

```js
export default function Dashboard(props) {
    // some props etc. were removed to keep this snippet simple
    
    // the state variable which causes issues
    const [courses, setCourses] = React.useState([]);
  
    // get Data from Python API
    React.useEffect(()=>{
        getData();
    }, []);
  
    /**
     * Gets the needed data (login status, courses, username) by calling the Python API
     */
    function getData() {
      window.pywebview.api.foo().then((foo) => {
        // do stuff
      }).then(() => {
        // fetch the courses from the Python API
        window.pywebview.api.getCourses().then((response) => {
          // try to update the state variable
          setCourses(response); // <------- throws the error
        }).catch((response) => {console.log(response);
      });
  
    }
  
    return (
      <Box>
        <MainAppBar />
        <Grid container spacing={0}>
            <Grid item>
              <MenuList />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <CourseList courses={courses} /> {/* passing the courses to the CourseList component */}
            </Grid>
            <FloatingSyncButton />
          </Grid>
        </Box>
    )
  }
  
  
  export function CourseList({ courses }) {
    
    // logic...
  
    return (
      <List>
      {/* trying to list each course item */}
        {courses.map((courseName) => {
          return (
            <ListItem
              key={courseName}
              disablePadding
            >
              <ListItemButton>
              <Checkbox/>
                <ListItemAvatar>
                  <Avatar>{courseName}</Avatar>
                </ListItemAvatar>
                <ListItemText primary={courseName} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          );
        })}
      </List>
    );
  }
```

---

**I would appreciate any help. Thank you!**

Comment: It looks like courses isn't there when you try to render it. maybe wait for courses to have valid data. try this in the JSX
```
{courses.length > 0 && <CourseList courses={courses} /> }
```

see what happens.

when you console log the response is there any data?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Conditional rendering didn't solve the problem. Yep, the log shows data.

Comment: have u tried aysnc await instead of nesting the .then inside another .then?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
      const api = await window.pywebview.api.foo()
      // do some stuff with api

      // fetch the courses from the Python API
      const courseList =  await window.pywebview.api.getCourses()
      setCourses(courseList);
      }
  catch (e) {
console.log(error)
}
    }
```

Comment: Just tried it... I am getting the data successfully but setting the state still raises the same error.