# In react, how to update specific property of an array state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a `state` of an array like this:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state={
      test_steps: []
   }
}
```

and it holds the following properties:

```
test_steps: [
    {
        description: "Test desc"
        expected_results: "Test exp. results"
        other_info: "test other info"
        status: true
        step_number: "1"
        _id: {$oid: "1234565894"}
    }
]
```

If I wanted to update only `**other_info**` property on this state, how will I achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: How do I update state.item\[1\] on setState? (with JSFiddle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537299/react-how-do-i-update-state-item1-on-setstate-with-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to get the your state and store it in variable. Then you loop the value and modify it. After that just set the state.

```
let test_steps = this.state.test_steps;
    test_steps.map((test)=>{
    test.other_info = "YOUR_UPDATED_INFO";
    return test;
    });

this.setState({test_steps});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is one element in your array you can use spread syntax, then change the related property.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
      test_steps: [
        {
          ...prevState.test_steps[0],
          other_info: "foo"
        }
      ]
}));
```