# Add image to the DOM dynamically in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a socket connection that updates a binary data.

By click I would like to update an image src  , the images are created blank with empty src and with id , but I did not found how do I doing something like :

```
$('imageId').src = 'new src' like in Jquery
```

I have array of images so I cant define per each image `this.ref` or something

my socket code: // here I want to update the specific image

```
   divSocket.on('data', (data) => {
        var bytes = new Uint8Array(data);            
        this.setState({
            imageSrc : someBufferFunction(bytes)
        })
    });
```

my render code

```
   { this.props.list.map((item,i) =>(
     <div className="img">
        <img  id={`cam${i}`} src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${this.state.imageSrc}`} />
     </div>
    ))}
```

the problem is that `this.state.ImageSrc` will update all images and will show socket data (video) in all the images

I can create an image with specific id in loop but how do  I update specific image via props/state

Comment: use an array? any todo example has an array rendering

Comment: Buy how do I add and update dynmaicly an img src tag , its not just data

Comment: You have an array of images but in your code there is only one image. Please edit your question to clarify this point.

Comment: updated, the data is live , i  dont have a list of images before , I need to make a placeholder

Answer (score 2):

You're using an array to display images ... from `props` ... `this.props.list`

This list should contain data for each image ... but `item` argument isn't used in `.map` rendering.

> I need to make a placeholder

Assuming that `props.list` doesn't contain any data ... used as loop counter ... renders placeholders only ... you need:

- an array of `src` in local state (`this.state.sources = [];`)
- you should render images using `key` prop:

> ```
> { this.props.list.map((item,i) => (
>     <div className="img" key={`cam${i}`} >
>       <img  id={`cam${i}`} src={this.state.sources[i]} />
>     </div>
> ))}
> ```

- you can use placeholder image for empty 'cells'

> ```
> <img  id={`cam${i}`} src={this.state.sources[i] ? this.state.sources[i] : "url_somePlaceholder.jpg"} />
> ```

New image from socket needs to update an **array element using index - not common one for all images** in `this.state.sources` - see [React: how to update state.item[1] in state using setState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537299/) for inspirations.

**If assumed earlier** `props.list` contains image sources at start - copy values into state (in `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` or `static getDerivedStateFromProps` )