# How to get index of parent object when clicking on inner property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this object of objects:

```
[
   0: {
      id: 0,
      name: 'Bob',
      children: [
        0: { id: 0, parent: 'Bob', 'name': 'Susan'},
        1: { id: 1, parent: 'Bob', 'name': 'David'},
      ]
  },
  1: {
     id: 1,
     name: 'Christine',
     children: [
        0: { id: 0, parent: 'Christine', 'name': 'Iker'},
        1: { id: 1, parent: 'Christine', 'name': 'Ray'},
        2: { id: 2, parent: 'Christine', 'name': 'Milo'},
     ]
  },
]
```

I have a list that renders all the children and I have an onClick on them. How can I get index of the parent's object when I click on the individual children itself? What I have below only returns the index of the child itself.

```
<div onClick={() => handleAddChild(id, index)}>
  <p>{child.name}</p>
</div>
```

Basically when I click on a child, I want to grab the index of that child's parent object in order to update the children list for that particular parent using setState(). So if I click Iker, I should get the index 1 back of Christine's object then update state using this method (but mine is dynamic): https://stackoverflow.com/a/49502115/10211209. If there another way to do this by matching the parent name property?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you want, but I'll try. You can always extract parent name, then iterate and search in original Object's values (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) the value with that name. But I bet there is a more elegant way of doing thing (like passing parent index into the function).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looping through and rendering the parents first and then the children. You could just pass through the parent index as an additional parameter. e.g

```
return this.parents.map((item, parentIndex) => (
    <span className="parent" key={index}>
        {item.children.map((child, index) => {
            <div onClick={() => handleAddChild(child.id, index, parentIndex)}>
                <p>{child.name}</p>
            </div>
        })}
    </span>
));
```