# Adding value to an array in useState but only at a particular index of the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have a piece of state which holds an array of comments.

Each comment has an array of replies.

How can I add a reply value to the replies array of a specific comment within the comments array?

Here is my current attempt:

```
      if (data) {

        const isLargeNumber = (comment) => comment.id === reply.commentId;

        const idx = comments.findIndex(isLargeNumber);

        setPost({
          ...post,
          comments: {
            ...comments[idx],
            replies: [data.replyToComment, ...post.comments[idx].replies]
          }
        })

        resetValues();
      }
```

`idx` holds the correct value I need but I do not think my implementation is correct here.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), since there isn't an actual question here.

Comment: @Lissy93 how is there not a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `post.comments` is an array, you certainly need to create an array, not a plain object with `{ }`. You are missing one level in your nested structure (the array of comments, versus the specific comment). You can use `Object.assign` to replace the entry at `[idx]`:

```
  const idx = post.comments.findIndex(isLargeNumber);

  setPost({
    ...post,
    comments: Object.assign([...post.comments], {
      [idx]: {
        ...post.comments[idx],
        replies: [data.replyToComment, ...post.comments[idx].replies]
      }
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Adapting from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49502115/18885543):

```
    setPost({
        ...post,
        comments: [
            ...post.comments.slice(0, idx),
            {
                ...post.comments[idx],
                replies: [...post.comments[idx].replies, data.replyToComment]
            },
            ...post.comments.slice(idx + 1)
        ]
    });
```