# How to get multiple selected options value in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

```
<Multiselect label='Select College' ref="collegeList" onChange={this.handleChange} multiple >
         <option value='college1'>college1</option>
         <option value='college2'>college2</option>
</Multiselect>
```

This component is from https://github.com/skratchdot/react-bootstrap-multiselect

What should be written inside the handleChange() function ?

Comment: Can you try to do `handleChange: function (event) { console.log(event); }` and see if it logs anything?

Comment: ya i have checked it but don't know which field to look for to get the selected elements.

Comment: Actually from `onChange` you receive the element itself being clicked, and a boolean value, true if the element was checked, false otherwise. You will find below my complete answer.

Comment: Check it out https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiselect-react-dropdown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `react-bootstrap-multiselect` doesn't seem to expose any sort of API for getting the currently selected items, so you'll have to query them from the DOM directly. Try something like this:

```
handleChange: function () {
    var node = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.collegeList);
    var options = [].slice.call(node.querySelectorAll('option'));
    var selected = options.filter(function (option) {
        return option.selected;
    });
    var selectedValues = selected.map(function (option) {
        return option.value;
    });

    console.log(selectedValues);
}
```

If you're using jQuery, this can be simplified a bit to:

```
handleChange: function () {
    var node = $(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.collegeList));
    var selectedValues = node.children('option:selected').map(function(option) {
        return option.value;
    });

    console.log(selectedValues);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's a much cleaner, es6 way to do it :)

```
let selected = [...this.refs.select]
  .filter(option => option.selected)
  .map(option => option.value)
```

There you go, all of the selected options!

Comment: Or instead of `[...this.refs.select]` you could do `Array.from(this.refs.select)`

Comment: or using `selectedOptions`: let selected = [...this.refs.select.selectedOptions].map(o => o.value)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to have a state in your component called `selectedItems`

The `onChange` callback then, takes as parameters `element` and `checked`, from the [Bootstrap Multiselect docs](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#further-examples). Element has the `val()` method, which returns the value assigned to the option.

Therefore handleChange could be implemented in the following way

```
handleChange: function (element, checked) {
    var newSelectItems = _.extend({}, this.state.selectItems);
    newSelectItems[element.val()] = checked;
    this.setState({selectItems: newSelectItems})
},
getInitialState: function () {
     return {selectItems: {}};
}
```

In this way, every time an element is clicked, its `checked` attribute is saved in the component state, which is quite handy if you need to change anything based on the `MultiSelect` selected values.

Please note that for the above code you need either the [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or the [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) library. This is necessary as React cannot merge nested objects, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933985/this-setstate-isnt-merging-states-as-i-would-expect).

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler and a direct way to get the values:

```
handleChange: function () {
   var selectedValues = this.refs.collegeList.$multiselect.val();
   console.log(selectedValues);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `selectedOption` that return a htmlCollection like this

```
 onchange(e){
        let selected=[];//will be selected option in select
        let selected_opt=(e.target.selectedOptions);
        console.log(selected_opt)
        for (let i = 0; i < selected_opt.length; i++){
            selected.concat(selected_opt.item(i).value)
        }

    }
```

and our select

```
<select  onChange={this.onchange.bind(this)} className="selectpicker w-100 rtl" multiple >
                    {this.state.list.map(obj=><option value={obj[this.props.val]}>{obj[this.props.name]}</option>)}
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

clean es6 code using `selectedOptions`

```
let selected = [...this.refs.collegeList.selectedOptions].map(o => o.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

React 16 with TS.

Note: refs are deprecated, that's why I used callback function to set Ref.

```
  private selectInput: any;
  private setSelectRef = element => {
    this.selectInput = element;
  };
  private handleMultiSelectChange = () => {
    const selected = [...this.selectInput.refs.MultiselectInternal.selectRef].filter(option => option.selected)
      .map(option => option.value);
     // there you can update your state using this.setState()
  };
```

...

```
<Multiselect data={data}
   onChange={this.handleMultiSelectChange}
   multiple={true}
   ref={this.setSelectRef}
   buttonClass="btn btn-default"
/>
```