# How to "update" state in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have this

— Ajax Callback :

```
        success:function(data) {
            self.setState({
                user: {
                    id_user: data.session.id_user,
                    firstname_user: data.session.firstname_user,
                    lastname_user: data.session.lastname_user,
                    action: "updateUser"
                },
            });
        }
```

— And handleChange on my inputs :

```
handleChange(){
    this.setState({
        user: {
            firstname_user: this.firstname_user.refs.input.value,
            lastname_user: this.lastname_user.refs.input.value
        }
    });
}
```

Give this :

```
 console.log(this.state.user);

 /*
   user
      firstname_user: "Blablabla"
      lastname_user: "Blablabla"
 */
```

Instead this : 
     console.log(this.state.user);

```
 /*
    user
      id_user: XX
      firstname_user: "Blablabla"
      lastname_user: "Blablabla"
      action: "updateUser"
 */
```

When `handleChange` is fired, `this.state.user` deletes `id_user` and `action` key. So `this.state.user` leaves only `firstname_user` and `lastname_user`. Why?

I didn't delete any keys so I don't understand why.

How to fix this please?

Thanks

Comment: @AndrewLi is right. setState sets the state of the object, not updates it. I think you can take a look at this duplicate as well. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25713365/763909

Comment: @newpatriks Yes, that's a way better duplicate target.

Answer (score 4):

`setState(nextStateObject)` performs shallow merge of `nextStateObject` into current state so nested objects (like `state.user` in your case) are not extended but overridden. You can use `Object.assign` to solve your problem:

```
handleChange(){
    let updatedUser = Object.assign({}, this.state.user, {
            firstname_user: this.firstname_user.refs.input.value,
            lastname_user: this.lastname_user.refs.input.value
        });
    this.setState({
        user: updatedUser
    });
}
```

Please check React [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) of `setState` method.