# should state be nested or flat

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example,

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    interactions: {
      liked: [],
      saved: [],
      receivedLikeRecently: null
  }
}
```

I'm trying to wrap my head around immutability, so if I wanted to now update `receivedLikeRecently` to `true`, would I have to do:

```
this.setState({
  interactions: {
    receivedLikeRecently: true
  }
});
```

What about the other values?  Do I need to include them as well?

According to the documentation setState does a shallow merge so I assume the other nested properties would not copy over right?  Or am I misunderstanding?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this.setState isn't merging states as I would expect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933985/this-setstate-isnt-merging-states-as-i-would-expect)

Comment: thanks.  dang ok.  i was just trying to unddrstand but i guess it has been asked before.  should i delete this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the nested state updates require more elaborate merging.

There is a concept of state normalization, described for Redux, but applicable to React state as well.
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

The thinking is, think of the state as of a relational data store to ease working with it.

Comment: Thanks.  So for redux as well I should keep it in mind?  If I understand assign (or spread operator) correctly, then as long as I use either, I can return the new object with however deep changes, correct?  I have not yet touched redux, sorry if sounds very stupid.. just going by what I read in the short time.

Comment: With the spread operator it is very simple and nice looking to return a shallow copy of your state. For nested states libraries like Normalizr are helpful, but don't rush, solve your React proper before moving onto Redux.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep your state flat in order to avoid deep merging, which must be done manually and can get pretty annoying, besides causing a performance hit if done frequently.

`Component.setState` uses a simple `===` to test if properties have changed, which will cause it to always update object-valued properties of the state object.