# React - Change a JSON Object in setState

Tags: reactjs

I have a form with three fields, the **handleChange** method works in the first field (DateOfBirth) but not in the (Id1) and (Id2) fields.

For some reason **setState** return this error when i try to change the value of the (Id1||Id2) fields.

***"A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component"***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Form extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { DateOfBirth:'1990-01-24', Metadata: {Id1:'33813518109', Id2:'John Doe'}}
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) { 
        const target = event.target;
        const name = target.name;        
        var value = target.value;         

        if(name === "Id1" || name === "Id2")            
            this.setState({Metadata:{[name]: value}});     
        else
            this.setState({[name]: value});
    }  

    render() { 
        return (             
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>                                          
                    <input name="DateOfBirth" type="date" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.DateOfBirth} />                                           
                    <input name="Id1" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.Metadata.Id1} />   
                    <input name="Id2" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.Metadata.Id2} />
                </form>
            </div>            
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this.setState isn't merging states as I would expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933985/this-setstate-isnt-merging-states-as-i-would-expect)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [react docs.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?#setstate)

> The output of the updater is shallowly merged with prevState.

Which means when you do

```
// name === 'Id1'
// value === 'dummy'
this.setState({Metadata:{[name]: value}});
```

then `Metadata` key in the state will have this shape:

```
{
  Metadata: {
    Id1: "dummy"
  }
}
```

Do you see the problem? Now input with `Id2` receives as value `undefined` (`this.state.Metadata.Id2` doesn't exist) which will make react throw an error about an uncontrolled component.

What you need to do to fix it is to make a full copy of nested object properties:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  Metadata:{
    ...prevState.Metadata,
    [name]: value
  }
}));
```

Comment: I understood THANK you so much