# Form issue in React: Controlled to uncontrolled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux-form

I have a FORM which just needs to store the values in state on submit.
I'm facing issue in doing so,

1. I only get value of last input in my formcontrol i.e:

   **formControls: qualification: "a"**
2. I get this error :  ***Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled.*** 
   *Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.*

I understood the above issue **so i declared my state inside constructor so my input element has the value even before onChange function is triggered.**
But this also doesn't seem to solve my issue.

Below is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import  './user.css';

class User extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                formControls: {
                 name: "",
                 age: "",
                 occupation:"",
                 hometown: "",
                 qualification: ""
                } 
             }   
        }


    detailsHandler = (e) => {
       const name = e.target.name;
       const value = e.target.value;
       console.log(name, value)
       this.setState({
        formControls: {
          [name]: value
        }
    });
    }
    submitFormHandler    = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state)

    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <div className="main-container">
            <div className="form-header">
                <p className="">Fill details here</p>
            </div>
            <div className="form-container">
            <form onSubmit={this.submitFormHandler}>
            <div className="form-row">
                <div className="form-label"><label>Name: </label></div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name" value={this.state.formControls.name} onChange={this.detailsHandler}/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-row">
            <div className="form-label"><label>Age: </label></div>

                <input type="text" placeholder="age"  name="age" value={this.state.formControls.age}  onChange={this.detailsHandler}/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-row">
            <div className="form-label"><label>Occupation: </label></div>

                <input type="text" placeholder="Occupation"  name="occupation" value={this.state.formControls.occupation}  onChange={this.detailsHandler}/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-row">
            <div className="form-label"><label>Hometown: </label></div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Hometown"  name= "hometown" value={this.state.formControls.hometown}  onChange={this.detailsHandler}/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-row">
            <div className="form-label"><label>Qualification: </label></div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Qualification" name="qualification" value={this.state.formControls.qualification}  onChange={this.detailsHandler}/>
            </div> 
            <div>

               <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default User;
```

Can someone help me to figure what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue comes from how you are setting state. As far as I know state updates are merges shallowly (https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged) which means that when you update the state you are erasing the values for the other form controls.

```
this.setState({
    formControls: {
      [name]: value  // the other values will be lost except for [name]
    }
});
```

You'll want to merge the form control values from the current state or include all of the values manually in the state update call.

```
const oldFormControls = this.state.formControls;
const newFormControls = Object.assign(oldFormControls,  {
    [name]: value
});

this.setState({
   formControls: newFormControls
});
```

Something like that.

Edit: When the form values are lost (null) then React puts the input in uncontrolled mode.

Comment: This is not true. `setState` only overrides the values you specify, leaving the others intact.

Comment: Unless a newer version of React has addressed this then it doesn't do recursive merging https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933985/this-setstate-isnt-merging-states-as-i-would-expect

Comment: Oh sorry I see, I missed the fact he is overriding formControls inside the state. In this case you are correct.

Comment: Okay understood the issue.. this works fine . Thanks a lot for your help.